# Devemos realmente fechar essa questão de redes? Que tal pô-la de modo aceitável por nós mesmos?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Estou me referindo a essa questão [**Dúvida teórica sobre redes**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241668/64969).

Em defesa da questão, ela trata de pontos que sinceramente considero importantes para quando se está programando sistemas remotos ou distribuídos. O primeiro foco dela é sobre *hosts* e *nós*. A segunda parte está com uma confusão aparentemente sem foco e possivelmente além da salvação sem ferir a integridade da intenção do AP. Mas entre coisas que mais me pareceram devaneios vem pontos sobre *saltos*, tabelas de rota e disponibilidade, assuntos pertinentes à quem vai fazer aplicação de alto desempenho sobre um sistema distribuído heterogêneo, como foi a integração dos diversos CENAPADs.

Eu particularmente não enxerguei muita questão de *hardware*, como questiona o @Articuno em seus comentários. Vejo muito mais sobre protocolo e camadas, e sobre arquitetura lógica.

Claro que a pergunta não é das melhores, não está tão bem formatada, a única tão aplicada é um tanto quanto falha (acredito que [nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomenclatura) seria essencial).

---

Depois de refletir, creio que [a resposta do Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6396/64969) seja realmente o posicionamento pelo qual mais sou inclinado. Mas isso não significa que o posicionamento do [Guilherme](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6391/64969) não tenha sido de incrível peso e de crescimento para mim. Também teve todos os comentários aqui e na pergunta específica, todos ressaltando com o devido respeito suas opiniões e julgamentos.

No final das contas, a pergunta não foi salva, e essa foi a decisão da comunidade. Mas posso dizer que fiquei feliz em ver o discurso e observar o posicionamento de todos. SOpt me enche de orgulho

Comment: Também não vejo problemas em relação a hardware, vejo mais o escopo de redes e protocolos. Isso é interessante não somente para sistemas distribuidos, mas, para qualquer aplicação Web atual. Diversos conceitos de rede tem impacto direto sobre a performance de interfaces web, se eles fossem discutidos, muito seria economizado em trafego e banda.

Comment: Eu fiquei na dúvida por isso não fiz nada.

Comment: @Maniero vou criar a tag **área-cinza** e adicionar nessa pergunta nela. Wiki da tag: se você acha que talvez possa se encaixar no assunto de programação mas seu coração está em dúvidas, essa é a tag certa pra você 8-) </joke>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concordo com o Guilherme, vou só adicionar o seguinte: mesmo que nós cheguemos a um consenso de que a pergunta é interessante, ela não pode ser salva como uma única pergunta. Há várias dúvidas:

- O que é um host;
- Algoritmo de rotas;
- Arquitetura de redes.

Acho que ela pode ser desdobrada em duas perguntas, de preferência três.

Quanto a estar ou não no escopo do site, acho que se adicionarmos algum tempero de como tratar essas coisas com programação os assuntos se alinharão mais com o nosso escopo.

P.s.: não pesquisei ainda por perguntas já existentes que cubram os assuntos acima. Talvez seja o caso de um moderador marcar a pergunta atual como duplicata de várias outras, se já existirem.

Comment: Acho que a questão de adicionarmos algum tempero depende muito da real duvida do cara, pode ser que nosso tempero seja apenas uma iguaria que nos agrada o paladar,mas, que não ajuda a sanar a fome do cara :D

Comment: @Intruso isso é válido, mas em geral as perguntas e respostas devem ser mais voltadas ao público em geral sempre que possível.

Comment: Então vamos tentar ajudar o cara a refinar a pergunta ;)

Comment: Depois de refletir, creio que esse seja realmente o posicionamento pelo qual mais sou inclinado. No final das contas, a pergunta não foi salva, e essa foi a decisão da comunidade. Mas posso dizer que fiquei feliz em ver o discurso e observar o posicionamento de todos. SOpt me enche de orgulho

Answer (score 5):

Podem ter usado o termo hardware, mas a questão não é se é hardware ou software, a questão é que a pergunta é sobre *infraestrutura*, o escopo do site é bem claro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

- um problema específico de programação
- um algoritmo de software
- ferramentas comuns entre programadores
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Creio que *infraestrutura* esta sim ligado a **WEB**, mas isto não quer dizer que **WEB** esteja ligado a desenvolvimento ou programação sempre.

Não vou negar a pergunta é sim interessante, eu gostaria sim de ver uma ou mais boas respostas nela, então no máximo só acho que ela seria interessante como "exceção" (assim como já houve outros casos), mas ainda sim não creio ser on-topic.

No entanto mesmo que interessante e mesmo que possa ser reaberta como exceção primeiro é necessário melhorar bastante a pergunta, tipo isto:

> Se eu, que estou no Rio Grande do Sul, estou solicitando algo de um servidor que está em São Paulo, quais são esses pontos que ele passa? Quais são esses roteadores?

Agora pessoalmente *'nesta altura do campeonato'* eu recomendaria que vocês indicassem pro AP um site da rede SE, mesmo que em inglês que fale sobre o assunto.

Não vou indicar nada porque não é uma área que eu domino e a pergunta tá é mesclado de várias perguntas, nem sei se todas serviriam em um mesmo local.

Comment: De fato, o fato de ser um _blob_ amorfo de várias perguntas e dúvidas torna a postagem da questão mais complicada

Comment: Nesse caso, sugerir dividir a pergunta em suas devidas partes atômicas e perguntar aqui as mais relevantes (digo, relativas à programação) seria uma atitude sensata?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado seria interessante, todavia temos que entender que mesmo dividindo ainda sim talvez este não seja o site ideal e mesmo que algo se 'salve' pro nosso site isto pode querer dizer que não vai sanar as duvidas do AP e que muito menos seja o que ele precisa de fato. Eu pessoalmente prefiro fechar mesmo e deixar o AP decidir por si o que é prioridade pra ele perguntar se assim ele desejar, claro que recomendo a você Jefferson, esperar opiniões além da minha aqui no Meta ;)

Comment: meu coração diz que eu deveria responder, minha alma diz que não tenho experiência no site para saber se realmente está no escopo do site, minha cabeça diz que estou com sono =]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu não vejo mal em arriscar uma resposta, mas claro pode ser excesso de esforço na verdade, ainda sim se procurar por perguntas fechadas com `closed:yes` irá notar que muitas tem respostas, claro que pra maioria não é o ideal, mas se for uma excelente resposta pode ajudar. PS: se o sono tá forte, melhor deixar pra amanhã hehehe :D

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado siga seu coração <3